# Rxjs observable subscriptions never publishing correctly

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs

One of my angular component needs to allow subscriptions to a number that it holds. I am trying to turn this number into an observable so others can subscribe to it.

my publisher looks like

```
private countChanged = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
public historyTimespanChanged$ = this.countChanged.asObservable();

private publish() {
    this.countChanged.next(this.count);
}

expandTimeSpan() {
    this.count ++;
    this.publish();
}

reset() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.publish();
}

getHistoricalCount() {
    return Observable.of(this.count);
}
```

my observer looks like

```
        this.historyComponent.getHistoricalCount()
        .subscribe(count => {
            if (count !== 0 ) {
                console.log('new history timespan expanded: ', count);
                this.historyCount = count;
                this.retrieveHistoricalData();
            }
        });
```

but the subscriber never gets called.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that instead of `this.historyComponent.getHistoricalCount()`, you might've meant `this.historyComponent.historyTimespanChanged$.subscribe(...)`, which derives from the `BehaviorSubject` that you're publishing to.

---

On a side note, to avoid the danger and tediousness of appending `this.publish` to every mutation of `count`, you may want to look into [`ReactiveProperty`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactiveproperty-rxjs) or do it yourself with ES6 setters:

```
class HistoryComponent {
  ...

  set count(value: number): bool {
    this.countChanged.next(value);
    this.count = value;
    return true;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, isn't the BehaviourSubject an Observable ? Should the OP not create a subscription directly to it ?

Comment: @adz5A It is; conversion to a true `Observable` via `asObservable` is just more defensive. It prevents a subscriber from accidentally polluting the Subject by sending values upstream.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the whole Class of the component ? Because if your subscribe is only called once, with 0 as its value your if clause will never run.

```
getHistoricalCount() {
     return Observable.of(this.count);
}
```

Returns an Observable of only one value : `v-|`, you should try to return the `this.historyComponent.countChanged` property which is updated by every `publish` call.

Comment: I dont have a countChanged property. Not following you

Comment: I suspect what you posted is the body of an es6 class, the declaration at the top `private countChanged = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);` is if I'm not mistaken a private field declaration + initialization. In short I meant returning `this.historyComponent.countChanged` which is an Observable of potentally infinite length, whereas `Observable.of(this.count)`is an `<Observable<int>>` of length 1.